# How do I add multiline statement inside chef gaurd?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In my recipe I have following resource that restart the computer but I want to apply guard on this resource.

```
powershell_script "Restart Computer" do
code <<-EOH

    $computer_name=$env:COMPUTERNAME
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer_name
    EOH
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    only_if reboot_pending?
end
```

I googled and found following ruby script for checking machine required reboot or not

```
def reboot_pending?

  # don't break when used as a mixin in contexts without #node (e.g. specs).
  if self.respond_to?(:node, true) && node.run_context.reboot_requested?
    true
  elsif platform?("windows")
    # PendingFileRenameOperations contains pairs (REG_MULTI_SZ) of filenames that cannot be updated
    # due to a file being in use (usually a temporary file and a system file)
    # \??\c:\temp\test.sys!\??\c:\winnt\system32\test.sys
    # http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960241.aspx
    registry_value_exists?('HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager', { :name => 'PendingFileRenameOperations' }) ||

    # RebootRequired key contains Update IDs with a value of 1 if they require a reboot.
    # The existence of RebootRequired alone is sufficient on my Windows 8.1 workstation in Windows Update
    registry_key_exists?('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired') ||

    # Vista + Server 2008 and newer may have reboots pending from CBS
    registry_key_exists?('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootRequired') ||

    # The mere existence of the UpdateExeVolatile key should indicate a pending restart for certain updates
    # http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832475
    (registry_key_exists?('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile') &&
          !registry_get_values('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile').select { |v| v[:name] == "Flags" }[0].nil? &&
          [1,2,3].include?(registry_get_values('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile').select { |v| v[:name] == "Flags" }[0][:data]))
  elsif platform?("ubuntu")
    # This should work for Debian as well if update-notifier-common happens to be installed. We need an API for that.
    File.exists?('/var/run/reboot-required')
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I tried to add this method inside guard but its not working.Is there any way to write multiline statement inside chef guard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef guards take in a block, like [the first example here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#not-if-examples). Blocks can be multi line, but can't have methods declared inside of them. If you copy the contents of the method you found and put them inside the `only_if` that should work.

```
powershell_script "Restart Computer" do
  ...
  only_if do
    <contents of method here>
  end
end
```

While this will work, the cleaner way to implement such an extensive guard is to put the `reboot_pending` method in a [library](http://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) and call that method from your recipe.